# Getting 404 when using rewrite rule for posts

Tags: posts, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, 404-error

So I need to have page slug Blog before post title I used rewrite rule to achieve this but doing this resulting me in 404 errors for paginations the below is the code I used to rewrite.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1 );
function my_new_default_post_type() {

    register_post_type( 'post', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public'  => true,
        '_builtin' => false, 
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog' ),
        'query_var' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
    ) );
}
```

This is the site URL [Blog Page](http://fdandc.stage.silver-rocket.com/blog/)
Rewrite is working good for this pages [Single Post](http://fdandc.stage.silver-rocket.com/blog/aliquam-erat-volutpat/)

but not for [Pagination](http://fdandc.stage.silver-rocket.com/blog/page/2/) please guide me in solving this issue.

Comment: You're trying to use a built in post type name "post". That won't go well.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook Then how will my requirement solved?

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of reserved post type names in WordPress that you can't overwrite. They can be found on the codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

'post' is one of them.

Comment: I know how to override post function all i am asking here is 404 error in when I click pagination.

Comment: @dh47 you can't create your own post type named 'post'